# Inconsistency with regex(anchors) in glibc

Tags: c, regex, glibc

I was experimenting with some regex stuff in C, namely trying to process a line in a text file:

```
MY NAME IS   ;;JOHN
```

I was using `sscanf` and matching with `%s %s %s %[^;]` in sscanf's format parameter. 
When I test this out with [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) (That is, I enter `[^;]` in the "Your regular expression:" field and `;;test` in the "Your test string:" field"), it matches the `test` data.

However, with the line

`sscanf("MY NAME IS   ;;JOHN", "%s %s %s %[^;], str1, str2, str3, str4)`,

the fourth string `str4` doesn't actually match. That is, `sscanf` returns `3`. 
To my knowledge, the regex `[^;]` matches any character other than the semicolon, so why does it seem `sscanf` is not matching anything in `;;JOHN`?

Is this just an issue with `sscanf`, or does glibc do regular expressions differently for some reason? Is it that `sscanf` is failing to match the fourth string because the first character in the string is indeed a semicolon, so it can't match the string exactly? And is that why it returns a 3?

In addition, if I have a line like `MY NAME IS   DOE;;JOHN` and use `sscanf`, the function does return 4.

Comment: The `scanf` functions doesn't do full regular expression matches.

Comment: Well, glibc does have regex support, but what do you mean by scanf not  having "full" regex matches?

Comment: The formatting in `scanf` are not regular expressions. The "character class" syntax is just similar to the regex variant, but it's not a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Here, see what [the manual page for `sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) says about regular expressions:

> 

To be clear, the quote above is empty since the word "regular" doesn't appear in the manual page. This is because the patterns used with `sscanf()` and friends are *not* regular expressions. You seem to expect them to be, which creates the confusion.

The character range syntax `%[]` is described like so:

> `[`
> Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set of accepted characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters in the string, plus a terminating null byte.
>
> The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed. The string is to be made up of characters in (or not in) a particular set; the set is defined by the characters between the open bracket [ character and a close bracket ] character.
>
> The set excludes those characters if the first character after the open bracket is a circumflex (^). To include a close bracket in the set, make it the first character after the open bracket or the circumflex; any other position will end the set.
>
> The hyphen character - is also special; when placed between two other characters, it adds all intervening characters to the set. To include a hyphen, make it the last character before the final close bracket. For instance, [^]0-9-] means the set "everything except close bracket, zero through nine, and hyphen". The string ends with the appearance of a character not in the (or, with a circumflex, in) set or when the field width runs out.

Comment: Based on the manpage for sscanf that you posted, it seems that `%[^;]` looks for strings without semicolons, but since it can't find any in `MY NAME IS ;;JOHN`, sscanf only matches 3 strings instead of 4? If that's the case, then why does `MY NAME IS DOE;;JOHN` receive a match, even if it has semicolons? (that is, why does sscanf return 4 for the latter string?)

Comment: `MY NAME IS DOE;;JOHN` matches since the semicolon can be part of a string, and `sscanf()` doesn't "look ahead" at the next pattern, so while starting the match for the 3rd `%s` at the `DOE`, it won't care that the next pattern excludes semicolons, so that single string will match all of `DOE;;JOHN`.

Comment: @unwind: The last token is `DOE` only. `;` is not read due to the character range syntax. http://ideone.com/yVH1bK